# Why does mod_jk on Ubuntu 14.04 not connect to tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, mod-jk, apache2.4

I am running tomcat 7, Ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4, Java 8. I am trying to hook up apache with mod_jk to use the tomcat application with only the static resources coming from apache.

Apache is running on port 80 and I can see the file structure and all my static resources. But when I go to the naked url, I only see the apache folder structure. In my understanding mod_jk should be forwarding to the ajp port of tomcat instead.

I installed apache2 and mod_jk (libapache2-mod-jk) by using apt-get. It basically did all the configuration for me (at least it looks like it did). I followed some tutorials to install it, but basically just checked and made sure the steps were taken. The main apache conf file is called apache2.conf and it includes all the .conf files from the folder called mods-enabled. Inside mods-enabled, there is a file called jk.conf. This is the mod-jk conf file and it includes a workers.properties file that is held in my /etc/libapache2-mod-jk folder. (I edited the workers.properties file to point to my tomcat home location and my java home)

The one thing that seemed different from most of the tutorials I read was that my mod jk conf file (jk.conf) had no reference to a file called module/mod_jk.so. I don't know what this file is, and why the folder doesn't have a slash in front of it, but that was what it looked like in all the tutorials.

What would really help is if someone has used the apt-get installation of mod_jk on Ubuntu 14.04 (all of the examples I found were for 12.04).

Is the reason it's not connecting because I don't have the .so file?
Am I mistaken about how ajp is suppossed to work, do I need to do any extra tomcat configuration other than have an ajp connector that looks like this `<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8080" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not added JkMount to apache2.conf. That solved this.